# Jasperreports server works fine with actual EC2, but not from an instance taken from the same AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, jasperserver, amazon-ami

I have an `EC2-1` which has a jasperreports server installed on it, and I could easily access it through http://IP_ADDRESS1:8081/jasperserver.
Now I have taken an image of `EC2-1`. once AMI is available, I launched a new `EC2-2`. As usual I logged in to `EC2` using SSH , and was able to run the script `./ctrlscript.sh start` ,to access the application. but when I tried to login to  http://IP_ADDRESS2:8081/jasperserver and run the report, I am getting below error in jasperserver.log and unable to get the report

```
300 ERROR WebServiceConnector,pool-4-thread-1:139 - Communication error java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
320 ERROR AsyncJasperPrintAccessor,pool-4-thread-1:321 - Error during report execution
```

can any one give me some clarification on my understanding of `**EC2 vs AMI**`.As per my understanding `EC2-1` and `EC2-2` has to be same. but in this case why I am not able to run the reports in `EC2-2`, when I am still able to run the reports in `EC2-1`.

Also please guide me if I am missing something here. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a new EC2 instance that was launched from an AMI taken of the original EC2 instance should include any configuration changes you made on your source instance.

From your description, it sounds like everything about the new EC2 instance is good: you can SSH into it, you can start JasperReports Server, and you can log into the web interface. The problems only begin when you try to run a report -- an important detail, because running a report has an external dependency on an external data source.

### Test Connection To Data Sources

In JasperReports Server Web UI, find your Data Source and go to its edit page to test the connection.  You should be able to find it at the bottom of the edit page for most data sources. For example, in the JDBC UI:

[image: JasperReports Server Edit Page for Data Sources, with Test Connection button highlighted in red.]

Try to test Jasper's connection to the data source from this page on your new instance.

### Verify Networking Rules

This reads to me like a networking error, specifically between the new EC2 JasperReports instance and the report's data source. There is likely a networking rule external to this EC2 instance that existed for your original instance, but wasn't updated for the new instance.  For example, if you had a security group that allowed inbound traffic from the original instance's CIDR to the data source, and it wasn't updated for the new instance's CIDR, you would see these sort of timeouts when JasperReports Server attempts to connect to the data source.

If testing the connection to the data source above failed, check external networking rules on resources such as [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules) or VPC [network ACLs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_ACLs.html#ACLRules), and verify that all rules for your original EC2 instance have been updated to also be valid for your new EC2 instance.